# psych FA biplot colour by group

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I'm trying to use psych to perform factor analysis and create a biplot in which points are coloured by grouping variable.

I want the biplot to group by colour and only plot points not group labels.

Documentation suggests passing `labels = NULL` will plot points using character supplied by `pch`. However, doing so reduces the plot to only the first group (setosa).

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the `group` argument? Your help is appreciated.
Example:

```
library(psych)

data(iris)

iris_fa <- fa(iris[,-5],
              nfactors = 2)

biplot.psych(iris_fa,
             labels=iris[,5],
             choose = c(1,2),
             pch=16,
             group = iris[,5])
```

[image]

I

Comment: Visualisation options for fa from the psych package are limited in comparison to fviz from factoextra which I have used for PCA. Is there a more powerful visualisation tool for factor analysis that allows for customisation similar to fviz?

Answer (score 2):

You specified `pch` with one value, but you need three. (Otherwise it's like saying 16, 0, 0.) So when you added `labels`, it ignored `pch`, and used that parameter.

```
biplot.psych(iris_fa,
             # labels=iris[,5],
             # choose = c(1,2),
             pch= c(16, 16, 16),
             group = iris[,"Species"])
```

[image]

Comment: Facepalm. Thanks for the help, I couldn't see that error for looking!